# Getting "FATAL EXCEPTION AsyncTask #1"

Tags: android

I'm getting the following error while running my application in Android. I don't have any background task going on.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>
> Process: com.inclov.inclovapp, PID: 32532
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening
>   provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{2363bbc5 32532:com.inclov.inclovapp/u0a161} (pid=32532,
>   uid=10161) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499) at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3503)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5062)
>   at
>   android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2737)
>   at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1446)
>   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:466) at
>   android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64) at
>   android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42) at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
>   at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
>   at
>   android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Its saying u missed android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS permission. Please add these permissions in manifest and try again

Comment: first go thru your logcat fully. it clearly shows requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

Answer (score 0):

add these to you manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

Read this for more info - https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html#Permissions

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error , you need these permissions :

```
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

or

```
android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

For lollipop and prior, you need to add this to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

If you are targeting Marshmallow, you need to add a request Permissions logic inside the activity using this. Follow this official [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on how to do it.